# Is It Safe to Expose The Bucket URL in a web app?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

Okay. Here’s my scenario.

I have a node app, where users can upload their profile pictures to. When the user uploads the image, it is saved in a Google Cloud Storage bucket, and I save the image URL in my database.

When retrieving the image to display in my front end, is it safe to expose the URL to the bucket directly? As in return the storage path given to me by GCP Cloud Storage and let my front end use that URL? Or should I do something to disguise/hide the URL for security reasons?

If so, how could I possibly go about this?

Obviously, I don’t want just anybody just playing with the different possible IDs and potentially accessing the profile images of other users. So, how would I go about hiding the URL?

Comment: If you don't want someone accessing images of other users, then you have to implement user authentication before serving them an image.  You have to know that the user requesting the image is authorized to see that image.  So, this goes deeper than not letting the client see the URL.  You need some real authentication checks before any user can see any user image.

Comment: Yes. I have authentication checks on my server app. However, my problem is that the URL where the image is stored is the URL of the bucket. What’s stopping somebody from just messing with the bucket URL and bypassing my server app altogether?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm saying you can't expose the bucket URLs to the outside world because they do NOT have user authentication checks on them.

Comment: Okay. So, how would I go about hiding it? Do I have my server app download the image file to my front end? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Whats going on right now is I have the authentication and all the security stuff. But, when an authenticated user requests the profile image, what is returned is the Google Cloud Storage bucket link. Which, you can technically just get from tge front end code and mess with.

Comment: I don't have any better idea than having your server proxy the image through an URL on your server that requires user auth.  So, client would request imageID xxx, your server would check user authentication and if it passes, it would fetch the xxx image from the cloud and pipe it to the client.

Comment: Okay. I guess I’ll stick with that for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls). They are good for this use case.

Your bucket should definitely be locked down in GCP IAM. Your application server should have access to the bucket through an IAM role that includes the ability to generate signed URLs for users. Then your client code can use that URL to access the object(s) directly out of Cloud Storage.

Keep in mind that users will still be able to see the URL for the bucket and object, but that won't matter because in this design the bucket's IAM permission doesn't allow them direct access. They will only be able to access specific objects with time-limited signed URLs. Only your server(s) will have access to read/write the bucket directly.

Comment: Ah. That is very helpful. Thank you very much.